# Using a combination of IF, And in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying make a condition in excel VBA where there are two posible condition of variable x and y,

Say for example

```
Sub Test()

X = 6
Y = 11

If X < 3 Or X > 5 And Y < 10 Then
    X = 10
Else
    X = 11
End If
MsgBox X
End Sub
```

For the X term, when `X<3 or X>5` seems work well however when i change the Y to any value greater than 10 say 11 then the result is 10 but supposed to be it should be 11. Can you please let me know if i missing something in my code so that when  `X<3 or X>5 and (y=11)>10` the result must be 11.

Regards,
Kenneth

Comment: Works for me as is???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub Test()

X = 6
Y = 11

If (X < 3 Or X > 5) And Y < 10 Then
    X = 10
Else
    X = 11
End If
MsgBox X
End Sub
```

Comment: hi Guys, thanks for the input, it is working perfectly now. though ive made my own syntax but it a bit longer like this: If Y<10 and X<3 Or Y<10 and X>5 Else.. I've got one follow up question though, is it allowed in VBA to have a multiple "And" and "Or" inside the IF-Else condition, say for example IF a<10 And b>3 Or a<10 And C>5 or a<10 And d>100.

Comment: @engrken  Yes..............use **parenthesis** to explicitly define the required logic

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue of operator precedence. In VB the order in **Logical and Bitwise Operators** is as follows:

1. Negation (Not)
2. Conjunction (And, AndAlso)
3. Inclusive disjunction (Or, OrElse)
4. Exclusive disjunction (Xor)

The result is that `and` is executed before `or` in your condition, leading to the right side of the `or` being the whole expression `X > 5 And Y < 10`.

Your condition is executed like:

```
If X < 3 Or (X > 5 And Y < 10) Then
```

I believe what you actually want is the following (this should solve your issue):

```
If (X < 3 Or X > 5) And Y < 10 Then
```

*Sources:*

- [MSDN: Operator Precedence in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893.aspx)